# Regular Expression for set of number and repeated words

Tags: regex

I need to find out the files similar to this

```
1234-JOHN-ebook.pdf
98749-RAJ-test.epub
```

Is there any regular expression that matches this format?

Comment: `/(.*)/` will match perfectly

Comment: Try to be more clear, the example is not.

Comment: Unless you want a RegEx that matches just those two strings and no others, it may be worth trying to explain more fully what values should be matched and (perhaps more importantly) what values should *not* be matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the capitalization will allways be as in your examples then: `\d+-[A-Z]+-[a-z]+\.[a-z]+`
if not, this will do `\d+-\w+-\w+\.\w+`.

please notice you might need to escape the dashes (\-)